# Validating an e-mail address using regex

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate e-mail addresses on my website and I have been trying to code up a demo of how e-mail validation would work with JavaScript. What I am trying to do is pass in the value of the e-mail address entered by the user to the validateEmail function and then print out 'valid' or 'invalid' in the div with the id 'result'. Because I am relatively new to JavaScript, I am not sure how to accomplish this and was wondering it if someone could show me an example of how to do this?

```
<head>
<title>Practice</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="post" method="practice.php">
        e-mail: <input id="email" type="text" onblur="validateEmail(execute(document.getElementById('email').value))" />
        <div id="result"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Is it the JS or the regex you are stuck with?

Comment: BTW there are nice frameworks that allow you to do JS validation almost declaratively. There's a JQuery validation plugin, for instance.

Comment: FYI If you're happy with HTML5, `type="email"` is probably more appropriate. See http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-email for details.

Comment: @Matt a little bit of both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you don't need to use `execute` method and can get `value` from `this` context:

```
validateEmail( this.value )
```

Then modify your function to print result:

```
function validateEmail(email) { 
    var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(re.test(email)) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'valid';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'invalid';
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I was lost as to how to use the test() function, and how to pass in the the value from the input field, this definitely clarifies, and works!! thanks again! :)